# unityのファイルアップロードに関して

Tags: unity3d

unityでサーバーにtextファイルをアップロードすることは可能でしょうか。
vpsは借りています。

Answer (score 1):

はい、できます。サーバーで、PHPのスクリプトが必要です。そして、Unityの中で、[WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html)のクラスを使ってください。

例えば、[このブログ投稿](http://unitydevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-upload-image-to-server-in-unity3d.html)を見てください。